# How to re-open same activity after application forcly stopped?

Tags: android

In my Android application i have a requirement to re open the same activity from where the application shut down or we manually force stopped it.

I can able to display the same activity but my application is losing all the datas. If you have any solution then please post.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean "application forcefully stopped"? you mean a crash?. if its a crash app is killed.

Comment: @Raghunandan yes .. just after posting that comment I realized this :D ... at first i thought crash

Comment: @Satyasarathi .. what kind of data are you using in those activity..

Comment: in onDestroy() you can save the state/data in shared preferences or sqlite db and use it to recreate the same state when the application starts again.

Comment: @RachitaNanda when app crashes it is killed i don't think onDestory() is called at that time

Comment: My Activity Flow is like this 
SplashScreenActivity--> LoginActivity-->Activity1-->Activity2
suppose i forcly closed my app at Activity1. When i will run it for 2nd time it should directly come from 1st Activity.
After Login I am populating Database and I have data that i am passing from Login to Activity 1 but if i am starting the Activity1 directly i am losing those datas.

Comment: @ Raghunandan thanks for correcting me . @ Satyasarathi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941193/where-does-force-stop-leave-an-activity-in-its-life-cycle This link suggests you should avoid long tasks and saving fast and often.

Comment: @Satyasarathi what does "forcefully" closed mean? a crash?

Comment: @ Raghunandan In Android emulator Go to Menu>>Manage Apps>>Click the app you want to force stop>>then click Force stop

Force stop means the application quits from the process list

Comment: @Satyasarathi then its killed. so you can do nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do that create your own Exception Handler, whenever app crashes you can redirect to any activity of your Application...

Comment: But it will start from begining of the application.That way we can do it but requirement is like start from that screen not from begining